# How to pass variables to an Apollo Mutation component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

Since version 2.1 Apollo Client uses React's render props pattern.

On the official [Apollo Client documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#basic) `variables` are passed as parameter to the mutation function:

```
addTodo({ variables: { type: input.value } });
```

however various tutorials, including [How to GraphQL](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/3-mutations-creating-links/), pass them as props:

```
<Mutation mutation={POST_MUTATION} variables={{ description, url }}>
```

What are there reasons for choosing one way or the other?

Comment: They're not mutually exclusive. Variables passed as props can be overridden when you call the mutate function that's handed to you in the render props, so you could view the second form as providing default values. In practice, I've never used the second form, I usually find myself wrapping the Mutation component around, say, a form, and calling the mutate function  when the form is submitted. But there could be some use for passing the variables as props when those are known beforehand and user input is not required or already known, for example a logout mutation, or a "like" action.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use either method of passing variables to the mutation.

Most of the time I would use the variables prop to set the variables since this is pretty clear and neat.

An instance where you might want to use the other method is when calling the mutation method from a child component - where the variables are also contained in that child component.

To follow on from the example code you gave above: Imagine an array of components on a ToDo list where each has an input but calls a single mutation (located in the parent component). It would be easier to call the mutation from inside each child components eg:

`updateToDoItem({variables: {id: this.props.id, text: this.state.text}})`